# Disable logging for Rails' internal queries for determining database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way of disabling the queries Rails uses internally to determine the database schema?

We're getting tons of queries like the following which clutters the log during development quite a lot:

```
SELECT column_name AS name, data_type AS sql_type, data_default, nullable,
virtual_column, hidden_column, data_type_owner AS sql_type_owner,
DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER', data_precision, 'FLOAT', data_precision,
'VARCHAR2', DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'RAW',
DECODE(char_used, 'C', char_length, data_length), 'CHAR', DECODE(char_used,
'C', char_length, data_length), NULL) AS limit, DECODE(data_type, 'NUMBER',
data_scale, NULL) AS scale FROM all_tab_cols WHERE owner = '***' AND
table_name = '***' AND hidden_column = 'NO' ORDER BY column_id
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724188/how-can-you-hide-database-output-in-rails-console

Comment: I don't want to disable AR logging entirely. I just don't want it to log the "internal" queries.